# XML completion in TextMate

Tags: xml, macos, textmate

How do I use XML completion with TextMate on Mac OSX? Does it even support XML code completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it currently does.

I've set up a schema and code completion works in AppCode and Oxygen. Doesn't work in XCode or TextMate. I tried installing the XMLMate plugin but it didn't help.

Not a very definitive answer, however since there have been no responses thus far. . . .